# Android- ANR Input dispatching timed out

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview

Im having this ANR on android 11. I was unable to find any proper solution for this even through its really complicated Stack trace to understand. Any Help will be appreciated.

**Stack Trace:**

> #00  pc 000000000007590c
> /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (syscall+28)   #00  pc
> 00000000001b067c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so
> (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+148)   #00  pc
> 0000000000674128  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so
> (art::GoToRunnable(art::Thread*)+480)   #00  pc 0000000000673f04
> /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JniMethodEnd(unsigned int,
> art::Thread*)+28)   at J.N.M0uS2SDH (Native method)   at
> org.chromium.content.browser.webcontents.WebContentsImpl.f0
> (chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-475810133:4)   at
> org.chromium.android_webview.AwContents.j
> (chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-475810133:3)   at
> com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.evaluateJavaScript
> (chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle.aab-stable-475810133:7)   at
> android.webkit.WebView.evaluateJavascript (WebView.java:892)   at
> com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.evaluateJavascript
> (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:3)
> at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.aM
> (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:1)
> at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.aH
> (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:3)
> at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.b
> (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972)
> at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.ac.h
> (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972)
> at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.webview.y.h
> (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972)
> at com.google.android.gms.ads.nonagon.ad.activeview.h.run
> (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)   at auj.a
> (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972)
> at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.f.a
> (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972:1)
> at auj.dispatchMessage
> (com.google.android.gms.policy_ads_fdr_dynamite@214106404@214106404057.409717972.409717972)
> at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:264)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8306)   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)   at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
> (RuntimeInit.java:632)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
> (ZygoteInit.java:1049)

Comment: Use try catch on possible places where this error could initiate from. If it is an exception then it will be caught giving away the actual reason for the error. If you want any further help share your code on where this error occured.

Comment: thats the problem the Stack Trace did not mention where excatly the anr is occurring,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your stack trace, lines containing `com.google.android.gms.policy_ads` seem to indicate that this is related to AdMob.

Looking at AdMob's support Google Group, there are a lot of complaints related to similar ANR's, just an example: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/rCZMplesYEc

Given that this is in an external SDK we as dev don't have much control over, I think the main course of action is to reach out to AdMob's support with issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same issue happen on apps, and the stack trace points to an issue with Google AdMob SDK, and particularly dealing with WebViews when showing ads.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @murari's answer is better than no answer at all. ANRs in general have very little information, and indeed they often lead to ad SDKs such as AdMob.